# Intel C Compiler and L"" prefix

Tags: unicode, prefix, icc

How can I define russian strings in Intel C Compiler?
In MSVS 2008 I do so:

```
_wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"Russian");
wprintf(L"текст");
```

And it works.
In ICC in doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose the problem, I'd check to see what values those characters are getting encoded as during compilation. With some code like:

```
wchar_t *x = L"текст";
for(int i=0; x[i] != L'\0'; i++)
{
  printf("%02x\n", x[i]);
}
```

You may want to change that `"%02x"` to `"%04x"` if `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`.

If the values are different, it is probably a compile-time problem where the compilers are using different encodings to interpret the source files.

I would avoid using code points >U+007F in source files, externalize strings to resource files and load them using an appropriate encoding. If you wish, you can try using Unicode escape sequences (like `L"\u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442"`).